# populate with objects in array - mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have two collections:

```
//col1
var schema1 = new mongoose.Schema({
              _id: ... ,
              name1: String,
              objects1: [{
                _id: ... ,             <-- reference to this !!!!!!!!!!!!!!              
                obj_name: String                            
              }]
});

//col2
var schema2 = new mongoose.Schema({
              _id: ... ,
              name2 : String,
              objects2 : [{
                _id: ... ,
                _source: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'col1'}
              }]
});
```

If I do something like

```
schema.statics.getByName = function(name, callback) {
    mongoose.model('col2').findOne({ name2 : name }).populate('objects2').exec(callback);
};
```

the return object gets not populated.

I'm quite sure the problem is, that the object i'm refering to is stored in an array, and that its not a document id.

I tried to solve this by doing `_source: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'col1.objects1'}` but without any effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: To which schema are you applying the static? If it is `col2` then you don't need to use  `mongoose.model('col2')` as `this` will be the model for `col2` (this is especially important if you define models on connections and not globally with mongoose). Does the `objects2` subdocument array have any other paths or is the entire subdocument meant to be a reference to `col1`? If so you don't need the `_id..., _source:..` just `[{type: mongoose.schema.ObjectId, ref: 'col1'}]`. If those assumptions are correct then those changes should help you on your way.

Comment: @JasonCust Hello, thanks for the nice reply. You are right with all the points you wrote. But it doesnt help my with my original problem of populating `objects2`.